# Multiple Events using Leaflet on Map and navigator.geolocation

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap, w3c-geolocation

I'm trying to get three events that happen on a `Leaflet` map:

1 Instantiate a `Leaflet` map with a single `marker`, which is also the centre of the map.

2 Use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` to get the user location, which updates **lat/lon** form fields, and put another `marker` on the map with those `coordinates`.

3 Upon clicking on the map, insert a third `marker`, again updating the **lat/lon** form fields.

I know `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, so this has to encompass pretty much everything.

**current**: I've accomplished the first point already.  I don't get the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` `marker`, but the form does update.  I also can't click for a new third `pointer marker`.

**question**: How can I get all three markers to function properly?

```
<div id="warning"></div>

<form method="post" action="#" name="meform">
  <label for="latFld">Lat/Lon</label>
  <input type="text" name="mylat" id="lat" value="44.444" readonly>,<input type="text" name="mylon" id="lon" value="-79.999" readonly> acc: <input type="text" name="myacc" id="acc" value="" readonly> metres
</form>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 95%; height: 500px;"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>

var homeIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl:      '/img/house_marker.png',
  iconSize:     [24, 24],
  iconAnchor:   [12, 24],
  popupAnchor:  [0, -24]
  });
var mymarkers = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([ 43.669128, -79.343001 ], {icon: homeIcon}).bindPopup("Get Gas Here")
  ]);

function foundLocation(pos) {
  myLat = pos.coords.latitude;
  myLon = pos.coords.longitude;
  myAcc = pos.coords.accuracy;
  document.getElementById("lat").value = myLat;         // form field
  document.getElementById("lon").value = myLon;         // form field
  document.getElementById("acc").value = myAcc;         // form field

  var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    center:       [ 43.669128, -79.343001 ],
    minZoom:      2,
    maxZoom:      18,
    zoom:         15,
    layers: [mymarkers]
    });

  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com" target="_blank">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
      }).addTo(mymap);

  L.control.layers(mymarkers).addTo(mymap);
  console.log("alpha");

  L.marker([ myLat, myLon ], {icon: homeIcon}).bindPopup("We measured you here<br>Accuracy: " + myAcc + " metres").addTo(mymarkers);

  mymap.on('click', function(e) {
  alert("clicked");
    document.getElementById("lat").value = e.latlng.lat;
    document.getElementById("lon").value = e.latlng.lng;
    L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]).bindPopup('Chosen Location').addTo(mymarkers);
    $('#warning').html("Values updated");
    });

  };

function noLocation() {
  document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Could not find your location";
  };

options = {
  enableHighAccuracy:     true,
  timeout:                5000,
  maximumAge:             0
  };

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation, options);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

```
<script>
var myLat = -79.999
var myLon = 44.444

var homeIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl:      '/img/house_marker.png',
  iconSize:     [24, 24],
  iconAnchor:   [12, 24],
  popupAnchor:  [0, -24]
  });
var mymarkers = L.layerGroup([
  L.marker([ 43.669128, -79.343001 ], {icon: homeIcon}).bindPopup("Get Gas Here")
  ]);
var chosenmarker = L.layerGroup([
  ]);

function foundLocation(pos) {
  myLat = pos.coords.latitude;
  myLon = pos.coords.longitude;
  myAcc = pos.coords.accuracy;
  document.getElementById("lat").value = myLat;         // form field
  document.getElementById("lon").value = myLon;         // form field
  document.getElementById("acc").value = myAcc;         // form field

  L.marker([ myLat, myLon ], {icon: homeIcon}).bindPopup("We measured you here<br>Accuracy: " + myAcc + " metres").addTo(mymarkers);

  var mymap = L.map('mapid', {
    center:       [ 43.669128, -79.343001 ],
    minZoom:      2,
    maxZoom:      18,
    zoom:         15,
    layers: [mymarkers, chosenmarker]
    });
  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a> Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com" target="_blank">Mapbox</a>',
        id: 'mapbox.streets'
      }).addTo(mymap);

  console.log("alpha");

  mymap.on('click', function(e) {
    console.log("clicked");
    chosenmarker.clearLayers();
    document.getElementById("lat").value = e.latlng.lat;            // set form fields lat
    document.getElementById("lon").value = e.latlng.lng;            // set form fields lon
    L.marker([e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]).bindPopup("Chosen Location").addTo(chosenmarker);
    $('#warning').html("Values updated");
    });

  L.control.layers(mymarkers, chosenmarker).addTo(mymap);
  };

function noLocation() {
  document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Could not find your location";
  };

options = {
  enableHighAccuracy:     true,
  timeout:                5000,
  maximumAge:             0
  };

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(foundLocation, noLocation, options);

</script>
```

First, provide variables and `layerGroups` (`Leaflet` objects), then start the `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.  `lat` and `lon` grabbed, the map made with centre-provided `lat` and `lon`.  Then comes the implementation of the second click-based `L.marker`, which triggers a clearance of that `L.layergroup` named **chosenmarker**, which also updates the form and places a `marker` on the map.  That will always be a single object.  That way the operand **chosenmarker.clearLayers();** won't erase the first two hard `markers`.